# JS Break my Random function

Tags: javascript, function, break

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

  elem = new Array('a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6','a7','a8','a9');
  $('.graphic').hide();

  hidden = false;
  time = 0;
  elem.sort(randomize);
  $.each(elem, function(i, r) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#'+r).fadeIn(400);
    }, time);
    time += 200;
  });

  time = 0;
  //elem.sort(randomize);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $.each(elem, function(i, r) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#'+r).fadeOut(800);
      }, time);
      time += 200;
    });
    $('.graphic').fadeIn(2400);
      hidden = true;
  }, 3000);

  $('.graphic').mouseenter(function(){
    if(hidden) {
      //time = 0;
      //elem.sort(randomize);
      $('.graphic').fadeOut(400);
      $.each(elem, function(i, r) {
        /*setTimeout(function() {
          $('#'+r).fadeIn(400);
          }, time);
        time += 200;*/
        $('#'+r).fadeIn(400);
      });
      hidden = false;
    }
  });

  $('.content').mouseenter(function(){
    if(!hidden) {
      time = 0;
      //elem.sort(randomize);
      $.each(elem, function(i, r) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('#'+r).fadeOut(800);
        }, time);
        time += 200;
      });
      $('.graphic').fadeIn(2400);
      hidden = true;
    }
  });

  $('.tile').click(function(t) {
    $(this).fadeOut(800, function () {
        window.location = $(this).attr("href");
      }
    ); 
    return false;
  });


  function randomize(){
    return (Math.round(Math.random())-0.5); 
  }

});
```

For some reason I am not able to break the effect.
When the side loads the banner is hidden. 9 elements come and go.
Everytime you enter the div, the banner fades out and the 9 divs in.
When I leave the enter, there is an random effect for fadeout.
But when I enter while that effect is going on, everything breaks.
So I need a break somewhere in there, so the fading stops and it will show my 9 divs instantly.
Any ideas? :/

Comment: Try to use the animation callback, or [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/), instead of so many `setTimeout`s. By using the effects queue this way, you will be able to easily [.`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using the http://api.jquery.com/stop/, to stop the currently-running animations